# jQuery click one button end up clicking all button with same class

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-5

I have a foreach loop that populates my page. This populates several input tags that are buttons, all the buttons have the same class.  When I click one button all the buttons are clicked.  Is there a way so when I only click one button it only responds to that button.  If I have twenty buttons and click a button I get 20 alert("test").  What do I change so I only get one alert("test").

Here is my HTML with some Laravel

```
<input class="interview-yes" id="{{$scan->id}}" type="submit" value="Yes"">
```

Here is my jquery

```
$('.interview-yes').click(function () {
  alert($(this.id));
)};
```

Comment: use id , if it is unique in your code , else this code will alert ids of everything which has .interview-yes class added to it

Comment: Have you written your jquery function direct inside `<script>` tags on page ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, yes I have.  It is in script tags inside a $document.ready

Comment: This is tied to a class. Tie to id using #.

Comment: @Aaron, try my answer. Hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: Can you include a working example to demonstrate the issue? Clicking one button should not fire the event for all buttons. See the [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/corfhy5d/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this method instead:

```
$(document).on('click','.interview-yes',function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
)};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am still having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Since your button are dynamic you need to `event delegate`.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.interview-yes', function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
)};
```

Here you go with an example

```js
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  $('body').append(`<input class="interview-yes" id="input_${i}" type="submit" value="Yes" />`);
}

$(document).on('click', 'input.interview-yes', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:
The behavior you have is coherent with the code you have written:
Install an event handler on each input of class "interview-yes", and call it on each one of them.

The behavior you want can be achieved better using .on ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ )

Quick example, given this html:

```
<div class="button-container">
  <input class="interview-yes" id="id1" type="submit" value="Yes"">
  <input class="interview-yes" id="id2" type="submit" value="Yes"">
  <input class="interview-yes" id="id3" type="submit" value="Yes"">
</div>
```

You can use this jquery code:

```
$('.container').on('click','.interview-yes', function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

As an added benefit, using this strategy, the event handler still works if you populate the container later via ajax/js.